# Visualforce rerender broken in IE11?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, internet-explorer

I've seen other issues with IE9 (that were patched) and a very specific question about IE11 rerendering with long text areas, but this seems to be a lot more general.  I built a simple rerender test and it works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 but is broken in IE11.  We have an Appexchange app and this is a major issue for us, because it looks like rerenders are broken everywhere.

It's easy to reproduce, and it does not seem to matter if I remove all empty spaces, remove the page header, within an iframe, not in an iframe, it simply never works in IE11.

VF page:

```
<apex:page id="thePage" controller="rerendercontroller">
<apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton id="thebutton" value="Change It" rerender="thevalue"/>
    <apex:outputText id="thevalue" value="{!time}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class rerendercontroller {

    public Integer getTime() {
        return system.now().second();
    }
}
```

Clicking the button in any browser except IE11 redisplays the seconds.  IE11 loads fine, but never rerenders.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `apex:outputText` in an `apex:outputPanel` and then rerendering the panel instead of the text?

Comment: It's worth noting that salesforce specifically doesn't support IE 11, at least last time I checked.

Comment: Yes, but just to confirm I updated the VF page with an outputPanel around the outputText and it still fails.  I did see somewhere that salesforce wasn't supporting IE11, but this seems to be a pretty major issue with a browser that is only going to become more widespread.  Hoping to find a workaround since this impacts existing managed packages too.

Comment: Arguably, given the security-broken nature of the browser, I hope it doesn't become more widespread. In fact, I'm hoping a new, safer browser emerges.

Comment: Totally agree.  Unfortunately MS is still the 800lb gorilla in the browser room.  Teaching clients to use a different browser can be problematic when many don't even know what a browser is!

Comment: Downloading Win 8.1 now... have you tried playing with Developer Tools (F12) and changing the Browser Mode / Document Mode? It might be a workaround for your clients to "downgrade" rendering engine temporarily.

Comment: Official support for IE11 was added in Spring '14. See the release notes under the Updates to Browser Support section: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf

Comment: Apparently the Spring '14 release missed this rerender issue, unless MS changed something mid-stream...which I wouldn't put past them.  I'm doing some further testing today, trying to find out exactly where it's breaking down.

Comment: Ok call off the dogs, I missed something dumb.  It was an add-on that killed the rerender, that I didn't even realize was running - Avast.  I never use IE and try to keep it clean, but that one snuck in there under the radar.  Disabled it and restarted IE11, and rerender works fine...albeit notably slower than other browsers.

Comment: Could you please post your last comment as an answer to your question? This question apparently has an answer, but it's still listed as unanswered. Thank you.

Comment: MarkL please post your final comment as an answer and mark your answer as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***Anser from Comments on Question***

> Ok call off the dogs, I missed something dumb. It was an add-on that killed the rerender, that I didn't even realize was running - Avast. I never use IE and try to keep it clean, but that one snuck in there under the radar. Disabled it and restarted IE11, and rerender works fine...albeit notably slower than other browsers.